# Keep fixed aspect ratio for div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a CSS Grid on my React app. The columns are the correct width already. In one of the cells of this grid, I want to add a `<div>` that maintains a fixed aspect ratio while stretching out (or shortening to) the width of the cell; meaning, the height should change responsively.

Note: because this `<div>` is part of a reusable component, I pass in the height and width of the `<div>` as inline styles for maxHeight and maxWidth. I want this to work even if there is no content within the div, as it is part of an animation sequence, and I need that space to be vacant.

**JS:**

```
<div className="img-container" style={{maxHeight: props.dimensions.height, maxWidth: props.dimensions.width}}>  (content goes here)  </div>
```

I then apply CSS classes to "img-container" to set width to 100%. Also to set background to 'red' just to see if it works.

**CSS:**

```
.img-container { width: 100%; background: red; }
```

But alas, no red shows up. I can see in dev tools that the width works, however there is no red on the screen as there is no height. Can someone clue me into what I can do to create this div with a red background of a fixed aspect ratio, that will resize **up or down** to fit the width of the cell of the grid?

Answer (score 0):

your `div` tag structure is incorrectly specified. you need like this:

```
<div className="img-container" style={{maxHeight: props.dimensions.height, maxWidth: props.dimensions.width}}>  (content goes here)  </div>
```

Comment: Ah yes sorry. It is that way, I mistyped on stack overflow :(

Answer (score 0):

You can achive the desired results by adding a child div with minimum width and minimum height to maintain the aspect ratio.

```
<div className="img-container" style={...styles}>   
   <div className='inner-div'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inner-div {
   min-height: 200px;
   min-width: 200px; 
}

//change the above values according to your requirements.
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer!

Let's work on my example provided, however change the JS and CSS as such, and also include an inner `div` with className 'img-inner' as an example.

**JS:**

Let's also insert paddingTop as a prop.

```
<div className="img-container" style={{maxHeight: props.dimensions.height, maxWidth: props.dimensions.width, paddingTop: `${props.dimensions.height/props.dimensions.width*100}%`}}>  (content goes here, e.g. a div with className="img-inner")  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img-container { width: 100%, position: relative }

.img-inner { position: absolute, top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }
```